# PHPExcel cannot open a file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to open an xlsx file, modify it and save it with another name. It's supposed to be quite simple but he doesn't work.

The file is 292 Ko , empty file with only 1 cell

Here is my code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
set_include_path('./lib/PHPExcel/Classes/');
require_once('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

ini_set('memory_limit','128M');

$toModifyPath = "./toModify.xlsx";
$outPath = "./out.xlsx";
$fileType = "Excel2007";


echo '<p>Starting...</p>';



//Open
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($toModifyPath) //<-- THIS LINE IS BLOCKING WITH NO ERROR
echo '<p>Opened</p>';


//Starting from here, it's working

//Modify
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C6', '4')->setCellValue('C7', '5')->setCellValue('C8', '6')->setCellValue('C9', '7');
echo '<p>Modifed</p>';

//Save
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
$objWriter->save($outPath);
echo '<p>Saved</p>';

echo '<p>Done !</p>';

?>
```

The output is "Starting..." So the line `$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($toModifyPath)` is blocking with no error and i dont understand why. Anyone gots a clue ?

PHP Version 5.2.3
PHPExcel 1.8

Comment: How big is the file `toModify.xlsx`?

Comment: 292 Ko , empty file with only 1 cell

Comment: do you have the excel file "toModify.xlsx" path declared is correct?

Comment: Check logs; check that the file really is an xlsx file, not simply a file with that extension (though that should give you a message pretty quickly)

Comment: When i change the path to have a bad one, i have an error message. So yes the path is good. And i got nothing in logs. (And i can open the xlsx file with office)

Comment: Being able to open the file with office doesn't mean that it actually is an OfficeOpenXML file, just that office can open it without complaining..... go to the "save as" menu (you don't need to actually save), but this will indicate what format the file will be saved as by default, and that's the actual format of the file

Comment: But without something more to go on, it's going to be almost impossible to diagnose the problem.... and you haven't even mentioned the versions of PHP and of PHPExcel that you're running; so unless you can glean some more information about what's happening, I'll simply file this as yet another "does not work" bug and ignore it

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.3
PHPExcel 1.8

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to load (or "read") an existing Excel file, than use the following code:**

Solution 1: You have to use a specific PHPExcel Reader

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$file_name = 'excel_file.xlsx';

// Choose a specific Excel reader
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
// $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
// $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2003XML();
// $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_OOCalc();
// $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_SYLK();
// $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Gnumeric();
// $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file_name);
?>
```

Solution 2: You can load any PHP Excel file using this code

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/phpexcel/IOFactory.php';
$file_name = 'excel_file.xls';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_name);
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain what in the code you have posted is an answer to the problem happening here, so that the user and future readers can learn from it?

Comment: I edited the answer with a more detailed approach :)